# How to get output of exec commandline in a build.gradle task

Tags: gradle, groovy, automation, build.gradle, devops

I need to test if specific packages are installed in a docker container. Therefore I have an array with the package names and their versions. I'm trying to write a task which iterates through this array, captures the output and checks if the version is correct. But I can´t get the output, it is always empty. Does someone have a tip or should I rewrite my task? I could write one task for each package that I am testing but I'm still trying to find a more generalised solution.

```
def packages = [
java11: "11.0.18", 
java17: "17.0.6"
]

tasks.register("testPackages") {
doLast {
    packages.each { key, value ->
        println "Package: $key, Version: $value"
        new ByteArrayOutputStream().withStream { os ->
            def result = exec {
                commandLine "docker", "exec", "$container", "/opt/test/$key/bin/java", "--version"
                def output = os.toString()
                println "the output is: $output"
                if (output.contains(value)) {
                    println "Package version: $value is correct"
                } else {
                    println "Package version is wrong"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
dependsOn(
    "startTestContainer",
)
finalizedBy "stopTestContainer"
}
```

This is the output:

```
❯ gradle docker:testPackages

> Configure project :docker
3.2.0-SNAPSHOT

> Task :docker:createTestContainer
Created container with ID '5d7169d83d052deaca6be14fb30e8ca5310a1d2d90b0501fbb109ffc31dd9d7e'.

> Task :docker:startTestContainer
Starting container with ID '5d7169d83d052deaca6be14fb30e8ca5310a1d2d90b0501fbb109ffc31dd9d7e'.

> Task :docker:testPackages
Package: java11, Version: 11.0.18
the output is: 
Package version 11.0.18 is wrong
openjdk 11.0.18 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.18+10 (build 11.0.18+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.18+10 (build 11.0.18+10, mixed mode)
Package: java17, Version: 17.0.6
the output is: 
Package version 17.0.6 is wrong
openjdk 17.0.6 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.6+10 (build 17.0.6+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.6+10 (build 17.0.6+10, mixed mode, sharing)

> Task :docker:stopTestContainer
Stopping container with ID '5d7169d83d052deaca6be14fb30e8ca5310a1d2d90b0501fbb109ffc31dd9d7e'.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 6s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed
```